# Como exportar los colores de Tailwind css a un modules.css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, nextjs, tailwind

Estoy haciendo una sidebar en react con next js, uso tailwind pero para esta sidebar necesitaba algo mas personalizado una vez finalizado queria coordinar con los colores de tailwind para asi funciona cambiarle el theme a oscuro con un boton y no queda bugueado, existe alguna forma para exportar los colores del tailwind a este css aparte? vi distintas formas y dan problemas, supongo que es porque el css personalizado es modules.css

Answer (score 0):

Yo tambien uso Tailwind.

No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Asi que por lo que entendi, si quieres llevar de algun lado a otro, algun color o estilo, lo que yo hago es asignarle un estado e irlo cambiando con el boton, como el tema oscuro.

Te puedo ayudar mejor si me replanteas la pregunta.